# How to transfer files between a remote Linux machine and a local Windows machine?

Tags: ftp, file-transfer

I need to transfer files/folders between a remote machine running Linux and my local machine running Windows XP. I usually access the remote machine through `ssh`, and sometimes use `VNC sessions`.

What is the easiest way to transfer a file from the remote machine to my local machine and vice versa?

- I think `ftp` should be the solution. Is there a better way?
- If `ftp` is a good option, how do I initiate the transfer? Do I need to setup ftp servers on both the machines and then transfer? What exactly needs to be done?

Comment: A little note, ssh/scp is encrypted and safe, ftp is unencrypted and unsafe. So if ssh works, don't switch to something that is unsafe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My recommendation is to use winscp on the windows side. This uses the SCP protocol, which works as long as you have SSH installed on the remote end... which you do.

Comment: As long as SSH is working properly, we use Filezilla, which also works with SSH to secure your transfer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup the server on the linux machine and the client from the windows machine.  [FileZilla](http://filezilla-project.org/download.php?type=client) is a common one I've heard of (it supports both linux and windows), but there are plenty other out there.  I'm assuming that you are NOT connected to the same network otherwise you would just setup a Samba share.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `ssh` access to the remote machine it means you also have `sftp` access (using the same user and pwd as the ssh).

This is because the port used by `sftp` is the same of the `ssh` protocol.

Try connecting using Filezilla and accessing it with the same credentials that you use for `ssh`, it will work!

Answer (score 0):

Dont overlook the simple solutions, such as up- and downloading the files via a Gmail or Ymail account.

Comment: Mailing is not a good solution. a) its cumbersome b) it has file size limits.

Comment: Then have a look at http://www.cross-copy.net. There is also a commandline client available.

Answer (score 0):

This is obvious to power users, but not to newbies:

If the machine acting as a server is behind [NAT](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FNetwork_address_translation&ei=JyB7ULnlDuaeiQLkkoH4BA&usg=AFQjCNE3M-Gg7yuoxBh5CKp2LjD13qOywA&sig2=5Ajbo_1D-Q3_SMwn8_qj-w), which is ubiquitous, you'll need to set up firewall/DMZ rules or rely on UPNP.  Something like http://miniupnp.tuxfamily.org/ could help, or check the documentation for the router that services the network the server is connected to.